# How to load data into pig using different PigStorage operator

Tags: apache-pig, hadoop2

I am new to Apache Pig and trying to load test twitter data to find out the number of tweets by each user name. Below is my data

```
format(twitterId,comment,userRefId):
```

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYEwB.png)

When I am trying to load data into Pig using PigStorage as (',') it is separating my comment section also into multiple fields because comments could also have','. Please let me know how to load this data properly in Pig. I am using below command:

```
data = LOAD '/home/vinita/Desktop/Material/PIG/test.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS (id:chararray,comment:chararray,refId:chararray);
```

Comment: Is it an option to modify the source data to use a different separator?

Comment: @darkownage: yes

Answer (score 0):

Load the record into a line,then replace ," with | and ", with |.This will ensure the fields are separated and then use STRSPLIT to get the 3 fields.

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(REPLACE(line,',"','|'),'",','|');
C = FOREACH B GENERATE STRSPLIT($0,'\\|',3);
DUMP C;
```

**EDIT:**
I used sample text to run the script and works fine.See below

[image]

Comment: While loading data as a line, it is loading only first field value in line and not the entire data... :(

Comment: @VinitaGupta What does your load statement look like?Do not use PigStorage.

Comment: @inquistive_mind I have used below statement for loading data as line: X = LOAD '/home/vinita/Desktop/Material/PIG/test1.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS (line:chararray);

Comment: That is incorrect.It should be X = LOAD '/home/vinita/Desktop/Material/PIG/test1.csv' AS (line:chararray);

Comment: @inquistive_mind Thanks for correcting me :) I have loaded the data as you have suggested and replaced ," with | and ", with | and after that replaced '|' with ','. But now it is treating data as a single column data and not 3 columns. So i am not able to group data by username for calculating number of tweets by each user name.

Comment: STRSPLIT($0,'\\|',3); will split it into 3 fields. Then do D = FOREACH C GROUP BY $2 which is the 3rd field after the split.E = FOREACH D GENERATE group,COUNT(C.$0); will give the count of tweets per user.

Comment: when i am trying to group data using your command(group_tweet = FOREACH tweet_c GROUP BY $2;) , it is throwing below syntax error: ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 10, column 30>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'GROUP'
 And when i am using(group_tweet = GROUP tweet_c BY $2;
), it is throwing below error:2017-04-18 21:56:09,904 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: 
<line 10, column 31> Out of bound access. Trying to access non-existent column: 2. Schema :tuple() has 1 column(s).

Comment: This will work.FLATTEN was missing in split. C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT($0,'\\|',3));
D = GROUP C BY $2;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE group,(C.$2); 
DUMP E;

Comment: Yes, you were correct Flatten was missing therefore it was not working. However I have applied one more correction to your command to get the number of tweets by each user, Please find below the changed command:F = FOREACH D GENERATE group,COUNT((C.$2));
Getting correct output now,Thanks for your help :) :)

Answer (score 0):

If changing the separator in your source data is an option, I would go that route. Makes it probably a lot easier to get started and to track down issues.

If you change your separator to a |, your code could look like:

```
data = LOAD '/home/vinita/Desktop/Material/PIG/test.csv' using PigStorage('|') AS (id:chararray,comment:chararray,refId:chararray);
```

Comment: I want to resolve this problem without changing the source data, Please let me know if this could be done